# Efficient way to assign values from another column pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, loops, numpy, if-statement

I'm trying to create a more efficient script that creates a new `column` based off values in another column. The script below performs this but I can only select one `string` at a time. I'd like to do this on all individual values.

For the `df` below I'm currently running the script on each individual `string` in `Location`. However, I want to run the script on all `unique` `strings`.

Description on how the new column is assigned: Each individual `string` in `Location` gets a value for the first 3 unique items in `Day`. So, for each value in `Location`, a new string gets assigned to the first 3 unique values in `Day`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = ({
    'Day' : ['Mon','Tues','Wed','Wed','Thurs','Thurs','Fri','Mon','Sat','Fri','Sun'],                 
    'Location' : ['Home','Home','Away','Home','Away','Home','Home','Home','Home','Away','Home'],        
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

#Select value
mask = df['Location'] == 'Home'
df1 = df[mask].drop_duplicates('Day')
d = dict(zip(df1['Day'], np.arange(len(df1)) // 3 + 1))

df.loc[mask, 'Assign'] = df.loc[mask, 'Day'].map(d)
```

At the moment I'm selecting each value in `['Location']`, e.g. `mask = df['Location'] == 'Home'`.

**I want to do it on all values. e.g. `mask = df['Location'] == All unique values`**

Intended Output:

```
      Day Location Assign
0     Mon     Home     C1
1    Tues     Home     C1
2     Wed     Away     C2
3     Wed     Home     C1
4   Thurs     Away     C2
5   Thurs     Home     C3
6     Fri     Home     C3
7     Mon     Home     C1
8     Sat     Home     C3
9     Fri     Away     C2
10    Sun     Home     C4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
def f(x):
    #get unique days
    u = x['Day'].unique()
    #mapping dictionary
    d = dict(zip(u, np.arange(len(u)) // 3 + 1))
    x['new'] = x['Day'].map(d)
    return x

df = df.groupby('Location', sort=False).apply(f)
#add Location column
s = df['new'].astype(str) + df['Location']
#encoding by factorize
df['new'] = pd.Series(pd.factorize(s)[0] + 1).map(str).radd('C')
print (df)
      Day Location new
0     Mon     Home  C1
1    Tues     Home  C1
2     Wed     Away  C2
3     Wed     Home  C1
4   Thurs     Away  C2
5   Thurs     Home  C3
6     Fri     Home  C3
7     Mon     Home  C1
8     Sat     Home  C3
9     Fri     Away  C2
10    Sun     Home  C4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# DataFrame Given
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Day' : ['Mon','Tues','Mon','Wed','Thurs','Fri','Mon','Sat','Sun','Tues'],                 
    'Location' : ['Home','Home','Away','Home','Home','Home','Home','Home','Home','Away'],                   
     })
Unique_group = ['Mon','Tues','Wed']
df['Group'] = df['Day'].apply(lambda x:1 if x in Unique_group else 2)
df['Assign'] = np.zeros(len(df))
# Assigning the ditionary values for output from numeric
vals = dict([(i,'C'+str(i)) for i in range(len(df))])
```

Loop to cut the dataframe for each line and checking the previous 'Assign' column info to assign new value

```
for i in range(1,len(df)+1,1):
    # Slicing the Dataframe line by line
    df1 = df[:i]
    # Incorporating the conditions of Group and Location
    df1 = df1[(df1.Location == df1.Location.loc[i-1]) & (df1.Group == df1.Group.loc[i-1]) ]
    # Writing the 'Assign' value for the first line of sliced df
    if len(df1)==1:
        df.loc[i-1,'Assign'] = df[:i].Assign.max()+1
    # Writing the 'Assign value based on previous values if it has contiuos 2 values of same group
    elif (df1.Assign.value_counts()[df1.Assign.max()] <3):
        df.loc[i-1,'Assign'] = df1.Assign.max()
    # Writing 'Assign' value for new group
    else:
        df.loc[i-1,'Assign'] = df[:i]['Assign'].max()+1
df.Assign = df.Assign.map(vals)
```

Out:

```
     Day    Location    Group   Assign
0   Mon Home    1   C1
1   Tues    Home    1   C1
2   Mon Away    1   C2
3   Wed Home    1   C1
4   Thurs   Home    2   C3
5   Fri Home    2   C3
6   Mon Home    1   C4
7   Sat Home    2   C3
8   Sun Home    2   C5
9   Tues    Away    1   C2
```

Comment: Thanks @Naga Kiran but I'm hoping to get it ordered as one `df` as per the intended output.

Comment: sry , i thought you are just facing problem in grouping the df, i edited the code to meet your requirement, but i couldnt figure out how C1 is repeated in "line-6" even after 3 consecutive values for given group

Comment: Thanks @Naga Kiran. Is it possible to have 'any 3 unique values'. Instead of specifically `['Mon','Tues','Wed']`. This will give me something to start off with though.

Comment: Yes @Maxibon we can have any  unique values. I just edited the code, mention your required unique values of day in Unique values list , then only those values listed as group1 and rest in group2

Comment: Sorry. Any 3 unique strings that aren't hard coded. The combination of 3 unique values is infinite. For instance, It could be `Mon, Tues, Wed` or `Sun, Thurs, Tues`. Basically any 3 strings.

Answer (score 1):

On the second attempt this works.

It was quite hard to understand the question.

I was sure that this should be done with pandas
groupby() and dataframe merging, if you check
the history of this reply you can see how I 
changed the answer to replace more slow Python
code with fast Pandas code.

The code below first counts the unique values per
location and then uses a helper data frame to 
create the final value.

I recommend pasting this code into a Jupyter notebook 
and to examine the intermediary steps.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = ({
    'Day' : ['Mon','Tues','Wed','Wed','Thurs','Thurs','Fri','Mon','Sat','Fri','Sun'],                 
    'Location' : ['Home','Home','Away','Home','Away','Home','Home','Home','Home','Away','Home'],        
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# including the example result
df["example"] = pd.Series(["C" + str(e) for e in [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4]])

# this groups days per location
s_grouped = df.groupby(["Location"])["Day"].unique()

# This is the 3 unique indicator per location
df["Pre-Assign"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: 1 + list(s_grouped[x["Location"]]).index(x["Day"]) // 3, axis=1
)

# Now we want these unique per combination
df_pre = df[["Location", "Pre-Assign"]].drop_duplicates().reset_index().drop("index", 1)
df_pre["Assign"] = 'C' + (df_pre.index + 1).astype(str)

# result
df.merge(df_pre, on=["Location", "Pre-Assign"], how="left")
```

Result

[image: result]

Other data frames / series:

[image: other data frames]

Comment: That's the crux of the question. I can run it on any particular `string` e.g. `Home` or `Away`. But if I have numerous `strings` it becomes inefficient to run the script on one `string` at a time. I'm hoping to get something that runs the script on all `unique` `strings`

Comment: Have you tried my example? It uses panda's internal grouping feature, which is really good at solving this - and it's fast. Like 100x faster than a Python loop. Note that my code never mentions "Home" or "Away".
The only reason "Away" is not grouped at the same time is that your example was empty there. By the way, make sure to apply `.astype("category", inplace=True)` to any dataframe column, which mostly has the same values. It will reduce memory useage and make your processing of large dataframe so much faster.

Comment: @576i it would be better to delete the answer whilst you wait. In this instance, some may choose to downvote and I'd hate to see that to someone attempting to help.

Comment: good comment... I managed to finally understand this, but will post a reply later because getting the groups right is hard... but it will work.

Comment: BTW, I made a %%timeit performance check and this solution takes less than half the time of the other solution (even with such a small data frame, with a large, proper data frame the difference should be much bigger)

Comment: This is good @567i but I'm not sure if I'm missing something. `['Assign']` doesn't appear when I run the code?

Comment: I'll also aim to provide a better description on what I'm hoping to achieve. The reference for each index should do this but I'll try beef up the content.

Comment: @Maxibon just to be safe I pasted the whole code into a Jupyter notebook and it produced the result. 

If you want to print the this from python, put a `print( )` around the last line. Like `print(df.merge(df_pre, on=["Location", "Pre-Assign"], how="left"))`. I tested this with Python 3.6. If you have problems, please describe how you test.

Answer (score 0):

Not as pretty, but much faster than the groupby/apply method...

```
def get_ordered_unique(a):
    u, idx = np.unique(a, return_index=True)
    # get ordered unique values
    return a[np.sort(idx)]

# split ordered unique value array into arrays of size 3
def find_ugrps(a):
    ord_u = get_ordered_unique(a)

    if ord_u.size > 3:
        split_idxs = [i for i in range(1, ord_u.size) if i % 3 == 0]
        u_grps = np.split(ord_u, split_idxs)
    else:
        u_grps = [ord_u]

    return u_grps

locs = pd.factorize(df.Location)[0] + 1
days = pd.factorize(df.Day)[0] + 1

assign = np.zeros(days.size).astype(int)
unique_locs = get_ordered_unique(locs)

i = 0
for loc in unique_locs:
    i += 1
    loc_idxs = np.where(locs == loc)[0]
    # find the ordered unique day values for each loc val slice
    these_unique_days = get_ordered_unique(days[loc_idxs])
    # split into ordered groups of three
    these_3day_grps = find_ugrps(these_unique_days)
    # assign integer for days found within each group
    for ugrp in these_3day_grps:
        day_idxs = np.where(np.isin(days[loc_idxs], ugrp))[0]
        np.put(assign, loc_idxs[day_idxs], i)
        i += 1

# set proper ordering within assign array using factorize
df['Assign'] = (pd.factorize(assign)[0] + 1)
df['Assign'] = 'C' + df['Assign'].astype(str)

print(df)

      Day Location Assign
0     Mon     Home     C1
1    Tues     Home     C1
2     Wed     Away     C2
3     Wed     Home     C1
4   Thurs     Away     C2
5   Thurs     Home     C3
6     Fri     Home     C3
7     Mon     Home     C1
8     Sat     Home     C3
9     Fri     Away     C2
10    Sun     Home     C4
```