# Assign running count to a new column in groups of 3 pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, assign

I am trying to assign a new `column` in a `pandas df` based off values in another 2.

In the df below, for each individual value in `Location` `(Home, Away etc)` I want to assign an increasing `integer` for the first `3` corresponding `unique` values in `Day`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = ({
    'Time' : ['7:00:00','8:00:00','9:00:00','11:00:00','12:00:00','1:00:00','2:00:00','3:00:00'],                         
    'Day' : ['Mon','Tues','Wed','Thurs','Fri','Thurs','Fri','Sat'],                 
    'Location' : ['Home','Home','Home','Away','Away','Home','Home','Home'],              
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

#Assign values from Home
mask = df['Location'] == 'Home'
df1 = df[mask].drop_duplicates('Day')
d = dict(zip(df1['Day'], np.arange(len(df1)) // 3 + 1))

df.loc[mask, 'Assign'] = df.loc[mask, 'Day'].map(d)

#Assign values from Away
mask = df['Location'] == 'Away'
df1 = df[mask].drop_duplicates('Day')
d = dict(zip(df1['Day'], np.arange(len(df1)) // 3 + 1))

df.loc[mask, 'Assign'] = df.loc[mask, 'Day'].map(d)
```

Out:

```
       Time    Day Location  Assign
0   7:00:00    Mon     Home     1.0
1   8:00:00   Tues     Home     1.0
2   9:00:00    Wed     Home     1.0
3  11:00:00  Thurs     Away     1.0
4  12:00:00    Fri     Away     1.0
5   1:00:00  Thurs     Home     2.0
6   2:00:00    Fri     Home     2.0
7   3:00:00    Sat     Home     2.0
```

Intended Output:

```
       Time    Day Location Assign
0   7:00:00    Mon     Home    1.0
1   8:00:00   Tues     Home    1.0
2   9:00:00    Wed     Home    1.0
3  11:00:00  Thurs     Away    2.0
4  12:00:00    Fri     Away    2.0
5   1:00:00  Thurs     Home    3.0
6   2:00:00    Fri     Home    3.0
7   3:00:00    Sat     Home    3.0
```

Comment: Consecutive # of values in `'Location'` maximum 3? or can it repeat more than 3?

Comment: There are ambiguities in how this might play out.  Please show a slightly bigger example explaining the logic.  Like, what happens if the 4th row was Thursday at Home?  I have several other questions but it takes too much time to put them all down.  You should be doing this work.

Comment: @piRSquared, In that instance it would still be `2` as it's over `3` `unique` values. `Row 5` would then become `3`.

Comment: @gyoza, it can repeat. So `Mon, Tues, Wed` would be `1`. `Thurs, Fri, Sat` would be `2`. It doesn't have to be ordered either. As in, it could be `Mon, Fri, Sat` for 1 and `Sun, Wed, Mon` for `2`. It's just the first `3` `unique` values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient way to assign values from another column pandas df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52215236/efficient-way-to-assign-values-from-another-column-pandas-df)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe need custom function with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and then convert values to numeric values by [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
def f(x):
    x1 = x.drop_duplicates('Day')
    d = dict(zip(x1['Day'], np.arange(len(x1)) // 3 + 1))
    x['new'] = x['Day'].map(d)
    return x

df = df.groupby('Location', sort=False, group_keys=False).apply(f)
df['new'] = pd.factorize(df['new'].astype(str) + df['Location'])[0] + 1
print (df)
       Time    Day Location  new
0   7:00:00    Mon     Home    1
1   8:00:00   Tues     Home    1
2   9:00:00    Wed     Home    1
3  11:00:00  Thurs     Away    2
4  12:00:00    Fri     Away    2
5   1:00:00  Thurs     Home    3
6   2:00:00    Fri     Home    3
7   3:00:00    Sat     Home    3
```

Another similar solution with `unique` instead `drop_duplicates`:

```
def f(x):
    u = x['Day'].unique()
    d = dict(zip(u, np.arange(len(u)) // 3 + 1))
    x['new'] = x['Day'].map(d)
    return x

df = df.groupby('Location', sort=False).apply(f)

s = df['new'].astype(str) + df['Location']
df['new'] = pd.factorize(s)[0] + 1
print (df)
      Day Location  new
0     Mon     Home    1
1    Tues     Home    1
2     Wed     Away    2
3     Wed     Home    1
4   Thurs     Away    2
5   Thurs     Home    3
6     Fri     Home    3
7     Mon     Home    1
8     Sat     Home    3
9     Fri     Away    2
10    Sun     Home    4
```

Comment: This is spot on jezrael but can we lose the `drop_duplicates`? If the same two values in `[Day]` and `[Location]` are repeated I'd like to assign the same `[new]` value

Comment: @Maxibon - Please check solution now.

Comment: You're a star. I had a more complex dataset that this code actually works on. I tried to simplify it here. If you wanted to post this answer there I'll make this question a duplicate. The link is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52215236/efficient-way-to-assign-values-from-another-column-pandas-df

Comment: @Maxibon - In my opinion there is no reason for duplicates, not sure if find time for your linked question, but I can try it.

Comment: @Maxibon - So added solution a bit changed - unique should be faster, the best test it.

Comment: If you just post the exact same answer in the linked question I'll accept it. I made the other question first.

Comment: @Maxibon - Sure, only last pard has to be changed, because in this question need only numeric output column.